# Name validation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, api

I have created a weather app but I am facing a problem when entering an invalid city name. How can I get a message that I have to insert a valid name? My code is here:

```
async function getCity(city) {
try {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY}`
  );
  const weatherInfo = await response.json();
  weatherInfo.ID = Math.random();
  setWeather([ weatherInfo,...weather]);
  setLoading("success");
} catch (error) {
  setLoading("error");
  setErrorMessage(error.message);
}
```

}

Comment: You can check some simple validation such as checking the undefined and empty passed value before the API call. But if the city name is not available you should handle this using the web API response.

Comment: Yes, but how can i do that?

Comment: use conditional rendering, have a boolean in your state, on success set it to true and on error set it false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional rendering on error display error component and on valid city name show city info.

```
const [showError, setError] = useState(false);

async function getCity(city) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${
        process.env.REACT_APP_OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY
      }`
    );
    const weatherInfo = await response.json();
    weatherInfo.ID = Math.random();
    setWeather([weatherInfo, ...weather]);
    setLoading("success");
    setError(false);
  } catch (error) {
    setLoading("error");
    setErrorMessage(error.message);
    setError(true)
  }
}
```

And render like the following

```
return (
 <div>
  { showError
    ? <div><h3>Please enter a valid city</h3></div>
    : <div>your input here and show city info</div>
  }
 </div>
)
```

DEMO

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;
const demoCities = ['London', 'Paris', 'Johannesburg'];

const Example = ({ title }) => {
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [cityInfo, setcityInfo] = useState("");

  let time;

  const getCity = () => {
    const cityIndex = demoCities.findIndex(cty => cty === city); //use toLowerCase() for comparison

    setLoading(true);

    if (cityIndex < 0) {
      setShowError(true);
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    time = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setShowError(false);
      setcityInfo(demoCities[cityIndex]);
      clearTimeout(time);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>{showError && "Please enter a valid city"}</p>
          <input
            value={city}
            name="city"
            onChange={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
          />{" "}
          <button onClick={getCity}>get city info</button>
          <p>
            {!showError && cityInfo && `Your selected city is: ${cityInfo}`}
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API should give you error if you fetch invalid city name so you can put some code in your catch statement to tell the user that invalid city name was entered.

```
    async function getCity(city) {
try {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_OPENWEATHERMAP_API_KEY}`
  );
  const weatherInfo = await response.json();
  weatherInfo.ID = Math.random();
  setWeather([ weatherInfo,...weather]);
  setLoading("success");
} catch (error) {
  setLoading("error");
  setErrorMessage(error.message);
  dispalyErrorToUser(...);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean (dispalyErrorToUser(...);) is function, how can i make his function ?

Comment: You can create this function to do whatever you want for example you can create html element for displaying errors under the field you enter the name of city and in the displayErrorToUser() function you can set innerHtml of that element to something like "invalid city name entered".